# vertical seekbar with listview in fragment android

Tags: android, fragment, seekbar

I have created a vertical seek bar right to customized list view in a relative layout.Under the relative layout i have another linear layout with some other text views.
That entire layout is fragment.
My question is vertical seek bar is not coming as i expected.I have given rotation as 270 for seek bar. Please give some suggestions.
sorry I don't have reputation to post image.

Thanks is in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        c.rotate(-90);
        c.translate(-getHeight(),0);

        super.onDraw(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isEnabled()) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                int i=0;
                i=getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight());
                setProgress(i);
                Log.i("Progress",getProgress()+"");
                onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

and in your layout use this

```
 <youpackagename.VerticalSeekBar
                            android:id="@+id/seek"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_bg"
                            android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_control" />
```

seekbar_bg.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

      <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#0F0F0F"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#000000"
                android:startColor="#000000" />
        </shape>
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#0F0F0F"/>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />

                <gradient
                    android:angle="270"
                    android:centerColor="#22e4fa"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#01a5db"
                    android:startColor="#0294d5" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Can u please provide those draw able. I have tried by extending seek bar.Its not worked.

Comment: Thanks its working...but i am trying to set width and height of seek bar pragmatically..means i need thin seek bar,but the thumb draw able is not placing exactly center to the seek bar line (horizontally).And one more doubt..thumb image is not coming on top edge of the seek bar on first instal,it always coming down edge.

Comment: for width use   android:maxHeight="somedp"

Comment: "seekbar1=(VerticalSeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seek);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams listParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(getPixelValue(20),seekbarHeight);
  seekbar1.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
  seekbar1.setLayoutParams(listParams);"

Comment: i am setting seek bar height like that pragmatically .i tried padding max height.but its not coming to center.

Comment: Thanks..Actually setting height and width pragmatically is not working..When i set in XML min width and height then its working good.but the thumb is starting from bottom of seek bar.